# Get data from XML/HTML page

Tags: java, html, xml, web-scraping

How to get data from XML/HTML page?

I'd like to make an android app, in which users get a notification of a school-lesson that fell out. 
This is what the website looks like: 
http://www.anony.ws/image/pC9

Users fill in their schoolclass (klas) after the installation of the app.
I want to pick the data from the table, users should receive a notification if it's their class. (example:

```
if ( userClass == klas ), then alert ("hey, " + was + " will be " + was + "because of" + opmerking);
```

something like that. But I have no idea how I should pick the data out of the table, it's a weird page. Makes it even more difficult because the page fades from (1/2) to (2/2) (max 10 listings each page, so 50 listings = 5 pages) , find out example here: http://suse.ghlyceum.nl/dagrooster/lwoo/.

How I should pick the data and put them in java vars?

Example from code I need to pick things out

```
<tr class='list odd'>
<td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
<td class="list" align="center">5</td>
<td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
<td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
<td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
<td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
<td class="list" align="center">D03</td>
<td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>
```

Full website code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Roosterwijzigingen Locatie Rijnwoude</title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<style type="text/css">
<!--

/* page title */
div.mon_title 
{   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;  
}

table.info
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
}

table.mon_list
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
}

td.info
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
 }

th.list,
td.list
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    font-size: 19pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
 }

-->
</style>
<meta name="generator" content="Untis 2013">
<meta name="company" content="Gruber &amp; Petters Software, A-2000 Stockerau, Austria, www.grupet.at">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FEE9B1">
<CENTER>
<TABLE  align="bottom" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
<TR>
<TD align="bottom">
<font face="Verdana" size="6" color="#911083">Roosterwijzigingen</font>
<br><font size="4" color="#000000" face="Arial">Vestiging Rijnwoude</font>
</TD>

<TD>&nbsp;</TD>

<TD>

<TABLE width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD><font size="-2">Gewijzigd 16-5-2013 13:54</size></TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>

</TD>

</tr>
</TABLE>
<p>

<font size="4" face="Arial">
<div class="mon_title">18-05-2013 Maandag</div>
<table class="mon_list" >
    <tr class='list'>
        <th class="list" align="center">Klas</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">uur</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">was</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">wordt</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">was</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">wordt</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Vaklokaal</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">opmerking</th>
    </tr>



<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">4H</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">5-6</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">nat1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">MEn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">aulauur</td>
</tr>

<tr class='list even'>
    <td class="list" align="center">4V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">econ3</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">econ3</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">SVn</td></td>
    <td class="list" align="center">SVn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">310</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>

</tr>

<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">5</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">D03</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>

</tr>

<tr class='list even'>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">8</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">gs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">NBa</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">aulauur</td>
</tr>

<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">nat7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">nat7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MEn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">JHo</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">001</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">het 6e of 8e uur</td>
</tr>


</table>
<p>
<font size="3" face="Arial">
Groene Hart Rijnwoude
</font></font>

</CENTER>
<p><center><font face="Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.grupet.at" target="_blank" >Untis roostersoftware</a></font></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be worth checking if there isn't a data service being used somewhere. Maybe you can use that service to get the data you need without parsing the html.

Comment: What data service do you mean?

Comment: Sometimes the data on the page is loaded through another call, for example: an ajax call is send to a REST service which returns some json that is used by the page to display the table. If there is such a service,  you might not need to parse the html. You can just use the service's response instead.

Comment: Hi Mike, sadly enough there isn't any data that is parsed, just leared gettting data from a JSON string. But on this page I need to parse html. Any help how I should do this in Java?